# How to generate a hash for each row of rdd? (PYSPARK)

Tags: hash, row, pyspark, rdd

As specified in the question, I'm trying to generate an hash for each row of RDD. For my purpose I cannot use `zipWithUniqueId()` method, I need one hash of all the columns, for each Row of the RDD.

```
for row in DataFrame.collect():
    return hashlib.sha1(str(row))
```

I know that is the worst way,iterating into rdd, but I'm beginner with pyspark. However the problems is that: I obtain the same hash for each row. I tried to use strong collision resistant  hash function but it is too slow. 
Is there some way to solve the problem?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your hashing method seems to be OK. Are you sure you use python in proper way? If you place provided code into a function it will always return hash of first row in dataframe as there is return inside loop.

You can calculate hashes in distributed way by going from Dataframe to RDD and perform mapping, for example:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> numbers = spark.range(10)
>>> numbers.show()
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  0|
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
|  4|
|  5|
|  6|
|  7|
|  8|
|  9|
+---+

>>> numbers.rdd.map(lambda row: hashlib.sha1(str(row)).hexdigest()).collect()
['ec0dbe879dee5ca3b0d5f80687993273213611c9', 
'd19469cfdac63a279b2068a989bebb8918af721a', 
'c5051bbf3ac45c49e29041b9bd840badd484fd94', 
'7916b1b00f01e1676a3ed7ff80e9614430c74e4d', 
'3ef92cd5a3abdbf996694ba08685676b26478121', 
'6e0820c8a947c2d0f53c2d2957e4d256f6e75f25', 
'2297e8b06e13cc79861aed7c919b5333dfe39049', 
'1b64fd47d48f2fc7d7d45a4c6e9b1958e973ab8c', 
'6e53b27c52c20e2fb2ffa5b3a1013c13fad21db7', 
'02d08951fde664abbbec94b37ab322e751c40e33']
```

Answer (score 7):

Check out [pyspark.sql.functions.sha2(col, numBits)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=sha2#pyspark.sql.functions.sha2) which returns the hex string result of SHA-2 family of hash functions (SHA-224, SHA-256, SHA-384, and SHA-512)

Available since Spark v1.5

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df2 = df.withColumn('my_col_hashed', F.sha2(F.col('my_col'), 256))
```

Comment: Hi how can I generate hash values based on multiple columns? Instead of `my_col`, can we use multiple column names here? I tried: `df2= df.withColumn('hash_id', f.sha2(f.struct(f.col('col1'),f.col('col2')), 256))` seems not working..

Comment: @wawawa, little late to respond here but you can definitely handle multiple columns. For example `df2 = df.withColumn('hash_id', F.sha2(F.concat('col1', 'col2', 'col3'), 256))`